# Add photo in Slide show?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys like to add a new slide in a slideshow , but I can not add thumbnails , I'm only managing to add the main image

Example: http://goo.gl/rwqRJd

Please someone help me?

Comment: Btw why all the downvotes? He provided a good example of his problem in the fiddle...

Comment: I agree. Downvoter, explain please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I don't know the plugin but I did a little workaround... Also, you have a nicer way to create elements in jQuery as you will see with `$(<div/>, options);`

Here's your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wu7k6af9/9/)

Comment: Thank you man, worked perfectly. I did not know how to work with this form elements with jquery .